# MySql syntax to set a non explicit default on column on table creation

Tags: mysql

Following is the input\output of mysql connection session:

```
Database changed
mysql> create table c(c1 varchar(20),c2 int,c3 int,not null(c1,c2));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not null(c1,c2))' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the right syntax and [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4e9bDRknPLMExyjgf4w8ej/0)

```
create table c(c1 varchar(20) not null, c2 int not null, c3 int);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to add not null in each needed column

```
create table c(
 c1 varchar(20) not null,
 c2 int not null,
 c3 int
);
```

Or you can set `c1` and `c2` as primary key

```
create table c(
 c1 varchar(20),
 c2 int,
 c3 int,
 primary key(c1,c2)
);
```